# Reading from multiple lists into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an input file which contains data like this:

```
[ABCD,color,NORMAL,N,2015-02-20,1]
[XYZA,color,NORMAL,N,2015-05-04,1]
[GFFD,color,NORMAL,N,2015-07-03,1]
[NAAS,color,NORMAL,N,2015-08-26,1]
[LOWW,color,NORMAL,N,2015-09-26,1]
[KARA,color,NORMAL,N,2015-11-08,1]
[ALEQ,color,NORMAL,N,2015-12-04,1]
[VDDE,color,NORMAL,N,2015-12-23,1]
[QWER,color,NORMAL,N,2016-01-18,1]
[KDSS,color,NORMAL,Y,2015-08-29,1]
```

I have created a variable which stores the columns names say table_columns. How can I convert this to a Pandas Dataframe?

Should be very similar to reading from multiple lists, but the number of lists that it will be reading from is n.

Comment: The data format seems unusual: without the square brackets it would be a simple csv file, which Pandas can read without a problem. Is there a reason why your data file contains square brackets?

Comment: Yeah, The data is coming from Spark's mapPartition method on a key-value pairRDD. It stores the data as a key and a list. I'm just using the value for Post processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""[ABCD,color,NORMAL,N,2015-02-20,1]
[XYZA,color,NORMAL,N,2015-05-04,1]
[GFFD,color,NORMAL,N,2015-07-03,1]
[NAAS,color,NORMAL,N,2015-08-26,1]
[LOWW,color,NORMAL,N,2015-09-26,1]
[KARA,color,NORMAL,N,2015-11-08,1]
[ALEQ,color,NORMAL,N,2015-12-04,1]
[VDDE,color,NORMAL,N,2015-12-23,1]
[QWER,color,NORMAL,N,2016-01-18,1]
[KDSS,color,NORMAL,Y,2015-08-29,1]"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp),header=None,names=['a','b','c','d','e','f'])

#remove []
df['a'] = df['a'].str.strip('[')
df['f'] = df['f'].str.strip(']')
#convert column e to datetime
df['e'] = pd.to_datetime(df['e'])
print df
      a      b       c  d          e  f
0  ABCD  color  NORMAL  N 2015-02-20  1
1  XYZA  color  NORMAL  N 2015-05-04  1
2  GFFD  color  NORMAL  N 2015-07-03  1
3  NAAS  color  NORMAL  N 2015-08-26  1
4  LOWW  color  NORMAL  N 2015-09-26  1
5  KARA  color  NORMAL  N 2015-11-08  1
6  ALEQ  color  NORMAL  N 2015-12-04  1
7  VDDE  color  NORMAL  N 2015-12-23  1
8  QWER  color  NORMAL  N 2016-01-18  1
9  KDSS  color  NORMAL  Y 2015-08-29  1
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer.

Comment: :-) If you accept any of the two - it should be this one.

Comment: @jezrael Hey Both of them worked, Thanks guys for the quick response. However, I used this one as pointed out by Ami Tavory. :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

import pandas as pd

>>> pd.read_csv(StringIO(open('stuff.txt').read().replace('[', '').replace(']', '')), header=None)
    D   color   NORMAL  N   2015-02-20  1
0   XYZA    color   NORMAL  N   2015-05-04  1
1   GFFD    color   NORMAL  N   2015-07-03  1
2   NAAS    color   NORMAL  N   2015-08-26  1
3   LOWW    color   NORMAL  N   2015-09-26  1
4   KARA    color   NORMAL  N   2015-11-08  1
5   ALEQ    color   NORMAL  N   2015-12-04  1
6   VDDE    color   NORMAL  N   2015-12-23  1
7   QWER    color   NORMAL  N   2016-01-18  1
8   KDSS    color   NORMAL  Y   2015-08-29  1
```